# Self changeable key

Tags: cryptanalysis

If key changes itself when it send/receive message what would be  could breaking method?
So:

$E: m×k$ in which $k$ is last generated key
$D: c×k$ in which $k$ is last generated key
$k{_n} = k_{n-1}×m$ method using for generating new key, both in decryption and encryption.

Note: $×$ marks any operation or function so $m×k$ is any operation or function using both $m$ and $k$.

So actual example would be:

$E: m\bigoplus k$
$D: c\bigoplus k$
$k{_n}=k_{n-1} + m$

I'm new to this site so if I did something wrong correct me.

Comment: Is the key changing between different communications, or within a single communication? The former is generally impractical (it requires you to know exactly what you've said to everyone you've ever talked to), the latter uses "key" differently than cryptographers use the term.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The security depends on the primitives used for encryption/decryption functions (the first two $\times$ operators) and the key derivation method (the last $\times$ operator).

XOR (usually depicted as $\oplus$ operator) - as used in your example - is only an encryption function if $k$ is a stream cipher. A stream cipher can be created if $k_0$ is a large enough value indistinguishable from random. Usually a stream cipher would not take (nor require) plaintext as input. Addition or modular addition (the $+$ operator) is certainly not enough to make a stream cipher. Instead you could use something like an algorithm based on a cryptographic hash function or block cipher.

Comment: _Usually a stream cipher would not take (nor require) plaintext as input_ But it would be more secure. Because if it use more _random_ (or not so random) data for creating key it would be more secure. Also this question doesn't have good encryption/decryption/new key generating because it's just an example.

Comment: That also depends on the algorithm used. A better answer than mine would explicitly mention what cryptographic properties the primitives should have. This is tricky though because the security requirements depend on the other function.